# Send data from 2 controllers on 1 request Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

So I have a rails application that acts as backend server for my ios app. My rails application has a Users controller and Avatars Controller. The Users Controller take care of the users and Avatars Controller take care of the users profile picture. The relationship between the User model and Avatar model is

`User has_one :avatar` & `Avatar belongs_to :user`

Each user `has_many friends`(User Model). Now I want to get all the friends of each user and send it to my ios client in a json format so I do this

```
@friends = @user.friends
@usernames = ""
for friend in @friends
    @usernames << friend.username + ","
end
respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => @usernames}
end
```

The for loop is so I send only what I need. It makes the data smaller and more secure because I don't send their auth_token. This works fine but now what I want to do is send each 'friends' avatar.What I did was I tried to use the `for` loop to append each avatar.image(I am using Carrierwave to upload my data and Cloudinary as my storage) to @avatars variable and send it but did not work. Here is the code:

```
@friends = @user.friends
@usernames = ""
@avatars = ""
for friend in @friends
  @usernames << friend.username + ","
  @avatars << friend.avatar.image + ","
end
respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => {users = @usernames, avatars = @avatars}}
end
```

Here is the error I get  `expecting tASSOC
...r :json =&gt; {users = @usernames, avatars = @avatars}}`

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: Updated the question to contain the error.

Comment: The problem is that you're doing `{users = @usernames, avatars = @avatars}`, which is wrong. It should be `{:users => @usernames, :avatars => @avatars}` or `{users: @usernames, avatars: @avatars}`.

Comment: But see my answer for a better approach altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you will have separate avatars and usernames, without any relationship between them. You'd better create an array of user hashes that contain username and avatar:

```
friends = []

@user.friends.each do |friend|
  friends << { username: friend.username, avatar: friend.avatar.image }
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => friends.to_json }
end
```

Comment: Tried this and it is better. Had to add an if/else clause to check if avatar exists. Other than that all was good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The message you're receiving is indicating a formatting error. Instead, pass your JSON as key-value pairs:

```
format.json {render :json => {'users' => @usernames, 'avatars' => @avatars}}
```

Comment: Thanks, had to choose the other answer because he posted a better approach to solving my problem but thank you for pointing that out.